# How do I solve "Uncaught Error: [News] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route>or <React.Fragment>"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a news app and this version 6 of react-router-dom is not working. Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

The code below gives me this error:

> Uncaught Error: [News] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a or <React.Fragment>

```js
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import News from "./components/News";
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/"><News key="general" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="general"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/business"><News key="business" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="business"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/entertainment"><News key="entertainment" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="entertainment"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/general"><News key="general" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="general"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/health"><News key="health" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="health"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/science"><News key="science" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="science"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/sports"><News key="sports" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="sports"/></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/technology"><News key="technology" pageSize={this.pageSize} country="in" category="technology"/></Route> 
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React-router-dom v.6 you should use `element` attribute:

```
<Route path="/" element={<News />} />
```

instead of wrapped components like

```
<Route path="/" element={<News />} > <News /> </Route>
```

as it did in version 5

see docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links